# How can i avoid COMException while adding multiple worksheets into a workbook using c# excel introp ?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create a workbook having multiple worksheets but i am getting COMException as soon i try to add 6th worksheet in the workbook. 
So is there any way to extend worksheets in a workbook ?? [image]

Comment: Mean's you were able to add 5 worksheet? show your code of how you are adding the worksheets

Comment: can you copy-paste your code...

Comment: There is no method for adding worksheets. All i do is to get worksheet from a workbook like this  
 m_ExcelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)m_ExcelSheets.get_Item(++m_CurrentWorkSheetInUse));
And if i do it iteratively in a loop, it throws exception once it reaches to m_CurrentWorkSheetInUse = 5;

Comment: Are you sure there are 6 worksheets in the Excel file?

Comment: No, I am not sure but i want to add 10 Million data rows in excel workbook and as per excel specifications one sheet can hold max 1048576 rows. So i need to add multiple sheets in a workbook but i am getting exception as soon i try to get 6th worksheet. And as per excel specifications there is no limit on having no of worksheets in a workbook it only depends on available memory of the hardware to which i have good configuration. AND as you see in the image Count property is set to 5 means workbook is holding only 5 worksheets so my question is how to extend it to more than 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a loop to get your worksheet in a loop and not sure how many sheets are there in the workbook then I would recommend finding the total Sheets count in that workbook and then looping to get the worksheet object

For example

`int SheetCount = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count;`

will give you the number of sheets in that workbook which you can use in a For Loop.

If you need more worksheets then you can use `xlexcel.Worksheets.Add` to get more worksheets.

**Followup From Comments:**

> I tried this approach, and Yes it's not throwing exception when i am trying to get worksheets beyond 5 from workbook. But It's overwriting data (which i am writing for 6th sheet) into 5th sheet only even i try to get 6th worksheet after adding one in workbook. It seems below code snippet returns last available sheet in a workbook which is 5th one. m_ExcelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)(m_ExcelSheets.get_Item(6)); How to stop overwriting data in the 5th worksheet after adding new worksheets ? – saurabh.mridul 1 min ago

The syntax of adding a worksheet is

```
 expression.Add(Before, After, Count, Type)
```

If you do not specify the paramenters in the `.Add` then the worksheet will be added as the first worksheet.

When you loop though the worksheets after adding a worksheet without specifying the parameters then your `worksheets(1)` becomes the latest worksheet that you added. And hence your worksheet 5 (now worksheet 6) gets overwritten.

You need to specify that the new worksheet that you are adding has to be added at the end of the existing worksheets.

**Description of parameters**

1. **Before**: (Optional) (Data Type: Variant) An object that specifies the sheet before which the new sheet is added.
2. **After**: (Optional) (Data Type: Variant) An object that specifies the sheet after which the new sheet is added.
3. **Count**: (Optional) (Data Type: Variant) The number of sheets to be added. The default value is one.
4. **Type**: (Optional) (Data Type: Variant) Specifies the sheet type. Can be one of the following XlSheetType constants: xlWorksheet, xlChart, xlExcel4MacroSheet, or xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet. If you are inserting a sheet based on an existing template, specify the path to the template. The default value is xlWorksheet.

Here is an example on how to add a worksheet at the end.

```
//~~> Add a new worksheet at the end of the worksheets
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, xlWorkBook.Sheets[xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. 
Sorry i didn't read your full comment as you were talking the same thing which i had already tried. 
Now, So can I extend to any number of worksheets in a workbook depending on my data rows ?

Comment: Yes you can :). If you are using Excel 2007+ then max rows that you can have in a worksheet is `1048576`. So if you have more than `5242880 (1048576 X 5)` rows then you will need the 6th Sheet.

Comment: I tried this approach, and Yes it's not throwing exception when i am trying to get worksheets beyond 5 from workbook. But It's overwriting data (which i am writing for 6th sheet) into 5th sheet only even i try to get 6th worksheet after adding one in workbook. It seems below code snippet returns last available sheet in a workbook which is 5th one. 
m_ExcelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)(m_ExcelSheets.get_Item(6)); 
How to stop overwriting data in the 5th worksheet after adding new worksheets ?

Comment: I had a feeling that you would ask this question :p. Updating my post. :)

Comment: Lolz, when you had the feeling Y didn't you cover in your last post ;)
i would appreciate if you could post the code snippet for same. 
And please tell me how to add sheets at last too.

Comment: Because I assumed that you will realize this on your own when you debug the code:) Anyways seee the updated post on how to add a worksheet at the end.